# Why Can't I Click, Scroll or Slide in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I just recently started to play Skyrim, but I was cut short by a major issue. I can click on hardly anything. When trying to open the menu and options, I'm fine. I can click on anything in the options menu. But when it comes to doing simple things like creating a character, I can't get the slider to move so I can adjust what he looks like.

I'm playing on a PC, Windows 7 64-bit. All of my computer components are well within the necessary guidelines to operate the game well.

Why can't I click on anything?

Comment: Did you pay for the game ? Or is it a torrent /hack / non legit version /etc?

Comment: Try alt tabbing out of the game and into it again.Also plug in a controller and check if it works .

Comment: Try different mouse. Any change?

Comment: I've found that in a lot of situations your supposed to use your keyboard instead of mouse.

Comment: The controls with the mouse do not work good. I often close a menu although I click on the lowest menu item(mostly "Misc"). Also the skill tree is horrible to navigate. But this has a reason: Skyrim is a console-port and thus preferably played with a controller.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a fix to your problem, but have you tried using the WASD, <kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and <kbd>E</kbd> keys to navigate those menus instead? If that doesn't work, and you happen to have a wired Xbox 360 controller laying around, you could try using that instead of a keyboard.